# step out and continue in MATLAB debugging

Tags: matlab, debugging

What is the difference between "step out (shift+F11)" and "continue (F)" in MATLAB debugger? When I debug a MATLAB function, both are triggering the cursor to come out of the loop. What is the exact difference between these two?

Answer (score 3):

Continue ([`dbcont`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbcont.html)) will cause the program to resume execution and will only stop once it encounters another breakpoint.

Step-Out ([`dbstep out`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstep.html)) will cause the currently executing function to continue and will automatically pause in the calling function regardless of whether you have a breakpoint there or not. Notice that this is referring to stepping out of a *function* and not a loop.

In your case, I'm assuming you only have a single function (or script) and therefore if you have no manual breakpoints after calling `dbcont` or `dbstep out`, they are going to have the same result since they will both just run the rest of the script to completion.